# Scrolling with ion-scroll

Tags: angularjs, html, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

I want to allow only one scroll type at a time (vertical or horizontal) with ionic scroll component. I tried "locking" attribute at ion-scroll element but no luck. When I drag diagonally it happen like the following image.

[image]

Please help me if you know a way to solve this. Thanks in advance.

Sample Code - http://play.ionic.io/app/720567016712

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<ion-content class="padding" overflow-scroll='false' locking="true" direction="xy" has-bouncing="false">
```

use this , Don't use ion-scroll now , remove it .. It will work as you want

Hope this helps you .. thanks

Comment: Thanks for the respond. But I need the content to be able to scroll both direction. I just do not want it to happen both at the same time like the picture I shown in the question.

Comment: hmmm .. okkk then I think setting locking to true is the best way (y)

Comment: I tried but it still not prevent diagonal dragging :(

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by using locking ="true"

and mention height and width for that ionic

Comment: you can check it on my example file, I did exactly what you said. But still not prevent from diagonal dragging.

Comment: can you please apply it on fiddle so that i can update that.

Comment: I tried. But it is not working some how. https://jsfiddle.net/ThetHlaing10/wwvvb52j/

So you can just update the play.ionic.io link I gave at the question. Feel free to update.

Comment: Update code on both links now its scrolling only in one axis https://jsfiddle.net/ThetHlaing10/wwvvb52j/ and http://play.ionic.io/app/720567016712

Comment: You can modify your html like this 
               
      <ion-content class="padding">
      <ion-scroll zooming="false" direction="x" locking="true">

Comment: See my last comment  -> 
 
You can modify your html like this <ion-content class="padding"> <ion-scroll zooming="false" direction="x" locking="true">